# changable Rootlayout Component from a page.tsx Nextjs App Router

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js13

- so basically i want to create a component that should be shown in all the pages hold the items that the user has selected so i made that component in the RootLayout of layout.tsx
  but the items will be in the page.tsx file .

if the user clicked on an item it will be added to list in the RootLayout

is it possible to make a connection between the two files ?

i tried to use the useState in layout.tsx but i found a difficultly to pass a function to the page.tsx that will add that item to  the list